# Ratingbar's rating within listview resets

Tags: android, listview, ratingbar

**Senario:** To get rating feedback for multiple multiple products.

**Problem:** Ratingbar value resets on scrolling listview by calling **setOnRatingBarChangeListener**

**Expected output:**

[image]

**Customized listview adpater code:**

```
public class FeedbackAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    static Context context;
    List<FeedbackRowDetails> row;
    ViewHolder holder;
    public FeedbackAdapter(Context context,List<FeedbackRowDetails> row)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.row =row;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView tv_slno, tv_productname, tv_time;
        RatingBar rb_productrating;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView( final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if (convertView == null) 
        {

            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_feedback_row_format,null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.tv_slno = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_slno);
            holder.tv_time = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_time);
            holder.tv_productname = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_productname);
            holder.rb_productrating=(RatingBar) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rb_productrating);
            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else
        {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        FeedbackRowDetails row_pos = row.get(position);

        holder.tv_slno.setText(String.valueOf(position + 1));
        holder.tv_time.setText(row_pos.gettime());
        holder.tv_productname.setText(row_pos.getproductsName());
        holder.rb_productrating.setRating(Float.valueOf(row_pos.getrating()));

        holder.rb_productrating.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new OnRatingBarChangeListener() 
        {
            public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating,boolean fromUser) 
            {
                FeedbackRowDetails row_pos = row.get(position);
                int roundoff_rating = (int)Math.round(rating);
                ratingBar.setRating(roundoff_rating);
                row_pos.setrating(String.valueOf(roundoff_rating));

            }
        });

        return convertView;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return row.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return row.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return row.indexOf(getItem(position));
    }

}
```

Comment: when doing this kind of work in listview like setting values for eg. checkbox,textviews and other fields you should also set them for else case also. That way they work properly, otherwise will get mixed up on scrolling

Comment: why you are calling setOnRatingBarChangeListener inside adapter?

Comment: to get the rating of the particular product, I am using it inside the adapter. Is this is right way? or any other way to implement this? I was implement for checkbox in same format it works.@mohit suthar

Comment: move `holder.rb_productrating.setOnRatingBarChangeListener` inside `convertView == null` if condition and check. Hope it works fine.

Comment: i tried holder.rb_productrating.setOnRatingBarChangeListener inside convertView == null but not working @Dinash

Comment: what content need to add in else part?? suggest some sample. @ vivek mishra

Comment: Does this issue solved???

Comment: @Dinash: This issue solved.  please check the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem solved with reference to [link](http://www.devexchanges.info/2015/11/rating-bar-in-listview-android.html)

```
  public class FeedbackAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        static Context context;
        List<FeedbackRowDetails> row;
        ViewHolder holder;
        public FeedbackAdapter(Context context,List<FeedbackRowDetails> row)
        {
            this.context = context;
            this.row =row;
        }

        private class ViewHolder {
            TextView tv_slno, tv_productname, tv_time;
            RatingBar rb_productrating;

        }

        @Override
        public View getView( final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            if (convertView == null) 
            {

                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_feedback_row_format,parent, false);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.tv_slno = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_slno);
                holder.tv_time = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_time);
                holder.tv_productname = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_productname);
                holder.rb_productrating=(RatingBar) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rb_productrating);
                convertView.setTag(holder);

            } else
            {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            holder.rb_productrating.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(onRatingChangedListener(holder, position));
            holder.rb_productrating.setTag(position);

            holder.tv_slno.setText(String.valueOf(position + 1));
            holder.tv_time.setText(getItem(position).gettime());

            holder.tv_productname.setText(getItem(position).getproductsName());
            float rating=Float.valueOf(getItem(position).getrating());

            holder.rb_productrating.setRating(rating);

            return convertView;

        }

          private RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener onRatingChangedListener(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) 
          {
                return new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating, boolean b) 
                    {

                        FeedbackRowDetails item = row.get(position);
                        int roundoff_rating = (int)Math.round(rating);                  
                        ratingBar.setRating(roundoff_rating);
                        item.setrating(String.valueOf(roundoff_rating));

                    }
                };
            }
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return row.size();
        }

        @Override
        public FeedbackRowDetails getItem(int position) 
        {
            return row.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return row.indexOf(getItem(position));
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap your codes present inside your onRatingChanged method with a simple if as shown below

```
if(fromUser) {
                FeedbackRowDetails row_pos = row.get(position);
                int roundoff_rating = (int) Math.round(rating);
                ratingBar.setRating(roundoff_rating);
                row_pos.setRating(String.valueOf(roundoff_rating));
            }
```

Have tested it with emulator and it was working as expected. Hope this solves your problem